# let realm = Realm() is freezing my app

Tags: swift, database, realm, local-storage, realm-mobile-platform

For some reason when I call 
`let realm = Realm()` it stops processing (doesn't crash) my code. Also when I try perform other query (add, delete, get and other) my app is still running, but the screen is frozen.

Comment: switch your code to : let realm = try! Realm()

Comment: You should post your code, give us the function that you use

Comment: Do you have a migration or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing try before Realm().

```
   let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
             // do something
            }
```